# how to make record editable while showing error message on vf page

Tags: visualforce, inlineeditsupport, edit

[image]

here in above image error message is displaying. But the record is saving while getting error. I want the error message as well as the record in editable mode.

vf-

```
<apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.HRMSStyle}"/>


<script>
window.onload=function()       
{        
    refreshTable();
};
</script>
<style> 
    .customTable{
    margin-left:50px;
    width: 82% !important;        
    }
    .pushbtn{
     margin-left:51px !important;
    }
    #menu{
    float:none !important;
    }
</style>
<apex:include pageName="HRMSHeader"/>
<apex:form >  
    <apex:actionFunction name="refreshTable" reRender="PanelID,PanelIDRej"/> 
        <apex:pageBlock >             

        <apex:commandButton value="Apply For Leave" styleClass="pushbtn" action="{!OpenPTORequest}" onclick="noRefresh()">
        </apex:commandButton>


        <table cellpadding="5px" class="customTable">
            <tr class="headerTr">  
                <th>Days Allotted</th>
                <th>Days Remaining</th>
                <th>Days Taken</th>
            </tr>
            <apex:repeat value="{!LstAllotment}" var="PTOAllot" id="pbt3" >
                <tr>
                    <td>{!PTOAllot.Days_Alloted__c}</td>
                    <td>{!PTOAllot.Days_Remaining__c}</td>
                    <td>{!PTOAllot.Days_Taken1__c }</td>
                </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </table>

        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!ListPL.size>0}" id="PanelID">                
               <br></br>
                 <div class="pageHeaderHRMS" style="width: 80.3% !important;margin-left: 51px;">Submitted Leaves</div>
                <br></br>

                <apex:outputPanel id="Refresh" rendered="{!ListPL.size>0}"> 
                   <apex:pageMessages id="s"></apex:pageMessages>

                    <table cellpadding="5px" class="customTable" >
                        <tr class="headerTr">                                
                            <th>Start Date</th>
                            <th>End Date</th>
                            <th>Half Day</th>
                            <th>Requested Days</th>
                            <th>Comments</th>
                            <th style="width:121px !important;">Action</th>                                
                        </tr>

                      <!-- <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listWrapper}" var="wrap">

                            <apex:column headerValue="StartDate">
                                  <apex:outputField value="{!PTOR.Start_Date__c}" rendered="{!isEdit}"/> 
                                    <apex:inputField value="{!PTOR.Start_Date__c}" rendered="{!NOT(isEdit)}"/> 
                            </apex:column>
                            <apex:column headerValue="EndDate">
                            </apex:column>
                            <apex:column headerValue="Half Day">
                            </apex:column>


                       </apex:pageBlockTable>-->

                       <apex:repeat value="{!listWrapper}" var="PTOR" id="tab">

                            <tr> 
                                <td>                                       
                                    <apex:outputField value="{!PTOR.le.Start_Date__c}" rendered="{!!PTOR.isEditable}"/> 
                                    <apex:inputField value="{!PTOR.le.Start_Date__c}" rendered="{!PTOR.isEditable}"/> 
                                </td>

                                <td> 
                                    <!--<apex:outputField value="{!PTOR.End_Date__c}" id="enddateid" rendered="{!isEdit}"/> -->
                                    <apex:outputField value="{!PTOR.le.End_Date__c}" rendered="{!!PTOR.isEditable}"/> 
                                    <apex:inputField value="{!PTOR.le.End_Date__c}" rendered="{!PTOR.isEditable}"/> 
                                </td>
                                <td> 
                                    <apex:outputField value="{!PTOR.le.Half_Day__c }" rendered="{!!PTOR.isEditable}"/> 
                                    <apex:inputField value="{!PTOR.le.Half_Day__c }" rendered="{!PTOR.isEditable}"/> 
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                   <apex:outputField value="{!PTOR.le.DaysCount__c}" rendered="{!isEditable}" />
                                   <!--<apex:inputField value="{!PTOR.DaysCount__c}" rendered="{NOT(isEdit)}"/>-->
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <apex:outputField value="{!PTOR.le.Comments__c}" rendered="{!!PTOR.isEditable}" />
                                    <apex:inputField value="{!PTOR.le.Comments__c}" rendered="{!PTOR.isEditable}" />
                                </td>
                                <td> 
                                     <!--<apex:commandLink styleClass="btn" style="padding:5px 6px;text-decoration:none" action="{!SavePendingLeaveTwo}" value="Save" rendered="{!NOT(isEdit)}" reRender="Refresh" status="actStatusId" onclick="noRefresh()"/>
                                     <apex:commandLink styleClass="btn" style="padding:5px 6px;text-decoration:none" action="{!CancelPendingLeave}" value="Cancel" rendered="{!NOT(isEdit)}" reRender="Refresh" status="actStatusId" onclick="noRefresh()"/>-->
                                 <!--   <apex:commandLink styleClass="btn" style="padding:5px 6px;text-decoration:none" action="{!EditLeaveData}" value="Edit"/> -->



                                        <apex:commandButton action="{!EditLeaves}" value="Edit" reRender="Refresh" >
                                        <apex:param name="editId" assignTo="{!opget}" value="{!PTOR.index}"/>
                                        </apex:commandButton>

                                         <apex:outputText value=" | " rendered="{!PTOR.isEditable }"/>

                                    <apex:commandButton action="{!SaveLeaves}" value="Save" reRender="s,Refresh">
                                        <apex:param name="saveId" assignTo="{!opget}" value="{!PTOR.index}"/>
                                        </apex:commandButton>

                              <!--        <apex:commandButton action="{!SaveLeaves}" value="Save" rendered="s">
                                      <apex:param name="saveid" value="{!PTOR.index}" assignTo="{!opget}"/>
                                      </apex:commandButton>-->

                                    <!-- <apex:param name="recrdId" assignTo="{!recid}" value="{!PTOR.id}"/>-->

                                     <apex:actionStatus id="actStatusId" >
                                        <apex:facet name="start" >
                                          <img src="/img/loading.gif" />                   
                                        </apex:facet>
                                      </apex:actionStatus>                                        
                                </td>                                    
                                <!--<apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblClick" />-->
                            </tr>


                   </apex:repeat>  

                    </table>
                </apex:outputPanel>            
        </apex:outputPanel>

        <apex:outputPanel id="Refresh2" rendered="{!ListApprovedLeave.size>0}">
            <!--<apex:pageBlockSection title="Approved Leaves" collapsible="false" columns="1">-->

            <br></br>
                 <div class="pageHeaderHRMS" style="width: 80.3% !important;margin-left: 51px;">Approved Leaves</div>
            <br></br>

                <apex:outputPanel id="refnewfresh" >
                    <table cellpadding="5px" class="customTable">
                        <tr class="headerTr">
                           <!-- <th style="width:110px !important;">Action</th> -->
                            <th>Start Date</th>
                            <th>End Date</th>
                            <th>Half Day</th>
                            <th>Requested Days</th>
                            <th>Comments</th>
                        </tr>
                        <apex:repeat value="{!ListApprovedLeave}" var="PTOR">
                            <tr style="display:{!IF(PTOR.Status__c='Approved','table-row','none')}">

                            <td>  
                             <apex:outputField value="{!PTOR.Start_Date__c}"  id="startid" rendered="{!isEditable}"/>
                             <apex:inputField value="{!PTOR.Start_Date__c}"  rendered="{!NOT(isEditable)}"/> 
                            </td>
                            <td> 
                             <apex:outputField value="{!PTOR.End_Date__c}" id="enddateid" rendered="{!isEditable}"/>
                             <apex:inputField value="{!PTOR.End_Date__c}" rendered="{!NOT(isEditable)}"/>
                            </td>
                            <td> 
                             <apex:outputField value="{!PTOR.Half_Day__c }" rendered="{!isEditable}"/>
                             <apex:inputField value="{!PTOR.Half_Day__c }" rendered="{!NOT(isEditable)}"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                             <apex:outputField value="{!PTOR.DaysCount__c}" rendered="{!isEditable}"/>
                            </td>
                            <td> 
                             <apex:outputField value="{!PTOR.Comments__c}" rendered="{!isEditable}" />
                             <apex:inputField value="{!PTOR.Comments__c}" rendered="{!NOT(isEditable)}"/>
                            </td>
                               <!-- <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblClick"/>-->
                            </tr>
                        </apex:repeat>        
                    </table>
                </apex:outputPanel>
           <!-- </apex:pageBlockSection> -->
        </apex:outputPanel>

        <apex:outputPanel id="Refresh5" rendered="{!ListApprovedLeave.size>0}">
            <!--<apex:pageBlockSection title="Approved Leaves" collapsible="false" columns="1">-->

            <br></br>
                 <div class="pageHeaderHRMS" style="width: 80.3% !important;margin-left: 51px;">Rejected Leaves</div>
            <br></br>

                <apex:outputPanel id="refnewfresh5" >
                    <table cellpadding="5px" class="customTable">
                        <tr class="headerTr">
                           <!-- <th style="width:110px !important;">Action</th> -->
                            <th>Start Date</th>
                            <th>End Date</th>
                            <th>Half Day</th>
                            <th>Requested Days</th>
                            <th>Comments</th>
                        </tr>
                        <apex:repeat value="{!ListApprovedLeave}" var="PTOR">
                            <tr style="display:{!IF(PTOR.Status__c='Rejected','table-row','none')}">

                            <td>  
                             <apex:outputField value="{!PTOR.Start_Date__c}"  id="startid" rendered="{!isEditable}"/>
                             <apex:inputField value="{!PTOR.Start_Date__c}"  rendered="{!NOT(isEditable)}"/> 
                            </td>
                            <td> 
                             <apex:outputField value="{!PTOR.End_Date__c}" id="enddateid" rendered="{!isEditable}"/>
                             <apex:inputField value="{!PTOR.End_Date__c}" rendered="{!NOT(isEditable)}"/>
                            </td>
                            <td> 
                             <apex:outputField value="{!PTOR.Half_Day__c }" rendered="{!isEditable}"/>
                             <apex:inputField value="{!PTOR.Half_Day__c }" rendered="{!NOT(isEditable)}"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                             <apex:outputField value="{!PTOR.DaysCount__c}" rendered="{!isEditable}"/>
                            </td>
                            <td> 
                             <apex:outputField value="{!PTOR.Comments__c}" rendered="{!isEditable}" />
                             <apex:inputField value="{!PTOR.Comments__c}" rendered="{!NOT(isEditable)}"/>
                            </td>
                               <!-- <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblClick"/>-->
                            </tr>
                        </apex:repeat>        
                    </table>
                </apex:outputPanel>
           <!-- </apex:pageBlockSection> -->
        </apex:outputPanel>

    </apex:pageBlock>

        <center>
            <div id="footer">
                <center>
                    <div class="headerFooterBlack">
                    </div>
                </center>
                Copyright &copy;. All rights reserved. <a href="http://www.techilaservices.com/"
                    target="_blank" title="Portal">Techila</a>
            </div>
        </center>

</apex:form>
```

here is a saveleaves method... where i should done changes

public void SaveLeaves(){

```
    integer counter=0;        
    for(WrapperClass w : listWrapper)
    {
       if(w.le.Start_Date__c >w.le.End_Date__c || w.le.End_Date__c<=system.TODAY() || w.le.Start_Date__c <=system.TODAY()){
                  listWrapper.get(opget).isEditable= false;}
            if(w.le.Start_Date__c >w.le.End_Date__c){
                counter++;
                listWrapper.get(opget).isEditable= false;

                ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Error,'End Date should be greater than or equal to Start Date'));
            }
            if(w.le.End_Date__c<=system.TODAY()){
                counter++;
                listWrapper.get(opget).isEditable= false;

                ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Error,'End Date should be greater than or equal to Today'));
            }
            if(w.le.Start_Date__c <=system.TODAY()){
                counter++;
                listWrapper.get(opget).isEditable= false;

                ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Error,'Start Date should be greater than or equal to Today'));                    
            }

    }
    if(counter==0){
        update listWrapper.get(opget).le;
    }

    // System.debug('Exception caught: ' + e.getMessage());

    system.debug('listWrapper.get(opget).le'+listWrapper.get(opget).le);
    listWrapper.get(opget).isSelected = false;
    listWrapper.get(opget).isEditable= false;


}
```

Comment: In your controller's `SaveLeaves` method, add a condition to validate the start and end date before resetting isEditable flag.

Comment: you dont want the record to be saved when there is an error? can you post your controller code?

Comment: please see the below post answer   for my method saveleaves

Comment: can you edit your question to add the controller instead of posting answer

Comment: done editing... kindly check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel below correction in code will help you to achieve what you desire:

```
   public Pagereference SaveLeaves(){
    integer counter=0;        
        for(WrapperClass w : listWrapper)
        {
           if(w.le.Start_Date__c >w.le.End_Date__c || w.le.End_Date__c<=system.TODAY() || w.le.Start_Date__c <=system.TODAY()){
                      listWrapper.get(opget).isEditable= false;}
                if(w.le.Start_Date__c >w.le.End_Date__c){
                    counter++;
                    listWrapper.get(opget).isEditable= false;

                    ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Error,'End Date should be greater than or equal to Start Date'));
                }
                if(w.le.End_Date__c<=system.TODAY()){
                    counter++;
                    listWrapper.get(opget).isEditable= false;

                    ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Error,'End Date should be greater than or equal to Today'));
                }
                if(w.le.Start_Date__c <=system.TODAY()){
                    counter++;
                    listWrapper.get(opget).isEditable= false;

                    ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Error,'Start Date should be greater than or equal to Today'));                    
                }

        }
    if(counter==0){
        update listWrapper.get(opget).le;
    }
    else{
     return null;
     }

    // System.debug('Exception caught: ' + e.getMessage());

    system.debug('listWrapper.get(opget).le'+listWrapper.get(opget).le);
    listWrapper.get(opget).isSelected = false;
    listWrapper.get(opget).isEditable= false;
    return null;

}
```

Your code counts through counter variable for occurrences of errors. If counter is not zero it shoud return back and show the errors. Page state must not be changed in such cases.

Comment: Void method must not return a value

Comment: See my code I changed the return type to pagereference from void.